# What causes BlockingOperationException in Netty 4?

Tags: java, netty

Recently, I find some `BlockingOperationException` in my netty4 project.

Some people said that when using the sync() method of start netty's ServerBootstrap can cause dead lock, because sync() will invoke await() method, and there is a method called 'checkDeadLock' in await().

But I don't think so. ServerBootstrap use the EventLoopGroup called boosGroup, and Channel use the workerGroup to operation IO, I don't think they will influence each other, they have different EventExecutor.

And in my practice, Deadlock exception doesn't appear in the Netty startup process, most of which occurs after the Channel of the await writeAndFlush.

Analysis source code, `checkDeadLock`, `BlockingOperationException` exception thrown is when the current thread and executor thread of execution is the same.

My project code is blow:

```
private void channelWrite(T message) {
    boolean success = true;
    boolean sent = true;
    int timeout = 60;
    try {
        ChannelFuture cf = cxt.write(message);
        cxt.flush();
        if (sent) {
            success = cf.await(timeout);
        }
        if (cf.isSuccess()) {
            logger.debug("send success.");
        }
        Throwable cause = cf.cause();
        if (cause != null) {
            this.fireError(new PushException(cause));
        }
    } catch (LostConnectException e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException(e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException(e));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException("Failed to send message“, e));
    }
    if (!success) {
        this.fireError(new PushException("Failed to send message"));
    }
}
```

I know Netty officials advise not to use sync() or await() method, but **I want to know what situation will causes deadlocks in process and the current thread and executor thread of execution is the same.**

I change my project code.

```
private void pushMessage0(T message) {
    try {
        ChannelFuture cf = cxt.writeAndFlush(message);
        cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws PushException {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    logger.debug("send success.");
                } else {
                    throw new PushException("Failed to send message.");
                }
                Throwable cause = future.cause();
                if (cause != null) {
                    throw new PushException(cause);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (LostConnectException e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException(e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException(e));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        this.fireError(new PushException(e));
    }
}
```

But I face a new problem, I can't get the pushException from the ChannelHandlerListener.

Comment: Of course you can't. You're throwing your own before you even get to look at it. The code involving `future.cause()` should be inside the previous `else` block, instead of what is there.

Comment: Your `pushMessage` throwing an `pushexception` doesn't work in the async world, it should return a Future for the operation, or use callbacks for the status

Answer (score 5):

BlockingOperationException will be throw by netty if you call `sync*`or `await*` on a `Future` in the same thread that the `EventExecutor` is using and to which the `Future` is tied to. This is usually the `EventLoop` that is used by the `Channel` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can not call await in IO thread is understandable. However, there are 2 points.
1. If you call below code in channel handler, no exception will be reported, because the the most of the time the check of isDone in await returns true, since you are in IO thread, and IO thread is writing data synchronously. the data has been written when await is called.

```
ChannelPromise p = ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
p.await()
```

2. If add a handler in different EventExecutorGroup, this check is not necessary, since that executor is newly created and is not the same one with the channel's IO executor.